# @Font face not working in any browser

Tags: html, css, fonts

I can't seem to get font face working. I've used this before without any problems, but in this case, I can't get it working in any browser!

```
    body {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Cusmyr;
    font-size:2em;
    margin:0em;

}

@font-face {
    font-family:'Cusmyr';
    src: url('font/myriadproregot.otf'),
    src: url('font/myriadproregsv.svg'),
    src: url('font/myriadproregtt.ttf');
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: ...and you have confirmed that the files are there and the path is correct (the directory "font" is in the same directory where the CSS file is)? Does the browser's developer tools confirm that the page loads the font files? If you change the body's font to something else it works (so something is not just overriding the style declaration)?

Comment: Yes, everything is OK! But the font still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The src attribute seems off to me. I think you need a single 'src' comma seperated. Also you're missing the format types. Not sure if that matters but couldn't hurt. Try this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cusmyr';
    src: url('font/myriadproregot.otf') format('otf'), 
         url('font/myriadproregsv.svg') format('svg'), 
         url('font/myriadproregtt.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The lines below indicates that your css file is in the root of the project or you got a font folder in your `Content` or `Css` folder. My money is that the font files are missing or the path is wrong.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Cusmyr';
    src: url('font/myriadproregot.otf'),
    src: url('font/myriadproregsv.svg'),
    src: url('font/myriadproregtt.ttf');
}
```

probably should be something like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Cusmyr';
    src: url('../font/myriadproregot.otf'),
    src: url('../font/myriadproregsv.svg'),
    src: url('../font/myriadproregtt.ttf');
}
```

Comment: Didn't work either! 

The CSS file is placed in the root where I've created a folder "font" containing the font files...

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't 'Cusmyr' be in quotes? Also have a look at this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ for ie6 fix